# One Horizontal and one vertical UICollectionView placed within a UIScrollView iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have two collection views within a scrollview. The above collectionview is a horizontal collectionview and the bottom one is a vertical. I am fetching all the data from api. And when I'm reaching at the bottom of the vertical collection view I need to hit a new api to fetch the new data. I am able to do that with the method willDisplayCell, but with that the problem I'm facing is UIScrollView. I can't scroll properly on my device. The bottom UICollectionView can not be scrolled smoothly. Can anyone suggest me something? Thank you

Comment: So what's your problem, UICollectionView cannot be scrolled smoothly?

Comment: Yes, the vertical scrolling of vertical collection view is the problem. Cause when I'm trying to scroll the collection view, the collection view as well as the scroll view,both are scrolling. That is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not put your collectionView in scrollView. Instead of doing so, put your horizontal collectionView as headerView in vertical collectionView.

Comment: implemented that way and it worked. Thank you very much.